# Accessing property in parentView from childViews

Tags: javascript, sproutcore

So I'm trying to make a splitview a bit more reuseable in my app but I'm stuck right now trying to make the bindings in the two content views easy to setup.

My topLeftView contains a SC.ScrollView which has a SC.ListView as its contentView. I would like to be able to set the contentBinding, selectionBinding, contentValueKey and contentCheckboxKey properties of the ListView when using the splitview and therefor have some properties in the splitview itself which the ListView uses. Does that make any sense?

So here's what I have:

```
SomeApp.MasterDetailView = SC.SplitView.extend({
...
masterViewControllerContent: 'SomeApp.someController.arrangedObjects',
masterViewControllerSelection: 'SomeApp.someController.selection',
masterViewControllerValueKey: "someKey",
masterViewControllerCheckboxKey: undefined,

topLeftView: SC.ScrollView.design({
   ...
            contentView: SC.ListView.design({
                contentBinding: masterViewControllerContent,
                selectionBinding: masterViewControllerSelection, 
                contentValueKey: masterViewControllerValueKey, 
                contentCheckboxKey: masterViewControllerCheckboxKey, 
        })
    }),

bottomRightView: SomeApp.DetailsView.design({
    ...
})
```

})

Referring to masterViewControllerContent gives an error but I can't seem to find anyways to go to the scope of the splitView when referring to masterViewControllerContent. Am I solving the problem the wrong way? Any suggestions to how this should/could be done?

Comment: Hi, can you please clearly define what is your class relationship is?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that? The relationship between the classes is that they are created as childViews in the SomeApp.MasterDetailView...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every view has a 'parentView' property.  So in the ListView you could bind to

```
'.parentView.parentView.masterViewControllerContent'
```

If you are creating a new view (App.MasterDetailView) then setting the content on the master detail, and having the child views bind in to that content is ok.

If you just have a SplitView with a Scroll and a List (i.e. the SplitView is not a special view that you are going to augment), though, I would bind the list directly to its content.

Comment: after thinking about it I agree with you about not putting it in the splitview.... =) thanks...

Comment: @jakob, cool. Note that if the splitview did need the content for some reason, you could define the binding in the split view *in addition to* defining the binding on the ListView.  Thats the great thing about bindings.  when the update, the changes get propogated.

Comment: @jakob, I misunderstood your intention with this question, so I clarified my answer.  If you are creating a special view (MasterDetail) that is going to need to access the content at the splitview level, then it is ok to bind into the parent view.